# Address breaks map display, why?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

Currently I am generating a Google static map by inserting an address through PHP insertion like this:

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=<?=$gmapadd?>&zoom=14&size=300x200&markers=color:blue|label:A|<?=$gmapadd?>&sensor=false">
```

Now here is an example output from this same script that displays properly:

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=11555+Central+Parkway+Jacksonville+FL+32224&amp;zoom=14&amp;size=300x200&amp;markers=color:blue|label:A|11555+Central+Parkway+Jacksonville+FL+32224&amp;sensor=false">
```

Here however, the output/address breaks the API (doesn't report an error, it just doesn't show the map), but I don't see the formatting problem or why it would break the map display. Also, if I enter this address into Google maps `5000-18 Hwy 17 #82 Orange Park, FL 32003` it does recognize it and display properly?

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=5000-18+Hwy+17+#82+Orange+Park+FL+32003&amp;zoom=14&amp;size=300x200&amp;markers=color:blue|label:A|5000-18+Hwy+17+#82+Orange+Park+FL+32003&amp;sensor=false">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "#" is not legal in a URL.  It needs to be encoded:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=5000-18%2BHwy%2B17%2B%2382%2BOrange%2BPark%2BFL%2B32003&zoom=14&size=300x200&markers=color:blue|label:A|5000-18%2BHwy%2B17%2B%2382%2BOrange%2BPark%2BFL%2B32003&sensor=false

Comment: Thank you - passed the variable through urlencode() before output and that fixed it. I appreciate the help.